# Concatenate EditText gives NullPointer Error

Tags: android

This is my [code](http://www.fpaste.org/HzoM/).

I am getting following error in logcat :

```
09-04 08:32:40.524: E/AndroidRuntime(644): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-04 08:32:40.524: E/AndroidRuntime(644): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-04 08:32:40.524: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at com.vodacom.nollyviewer.Searchnolly.SearchVideos(Searchnolly.java:109)
09-04 08:32:40.524: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at com.vodacom.nollyviewer.Searchnolly$1.onClick(Searchnolly.java:71)
09-04 08:32:40.524: E/AndroidRuntime(644):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is code at line number: 109 of file Searchnolly.java?

Comment: prolly `findViewById(R.id.resultdisplay);` returns null so  `resultdisplay` is null ...

Comment: put this line in oncreate() of activity editTextProducer = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextProducer);

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in OnCreate()

```
resultdisplay = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.resultdisplay);
```

You may set it's visibility to "View.GONE" or "View.INVISIBLE" if you do not want to display the resultdisplay

Answer (score 0):

Since you are declaring edittext in the onclicklistener it will be null since the context is incorrect.So try declaring all the edittexts in the oncreate itself.

Answer (score 0):

Define below in your Code :

```
private String searchresult="";
```

may be you do not have intialized your String searchresult String that is why you are getting this type of error. Hope it will Help you.

Answer (score 0):

Do all the initialization in oncreate() of activity. Your code should look like this

```
this.buttonProducer = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.buttonProducer);
    FixedText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FixedText1);
    FixedText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FixedText2);
    buttonProducer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonProducer);
    editTextProducer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextProducer);
    ConcatFixedTexts = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ConcatFixedTexts);
    resultdisplay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.resultdisplay);
```

And also remove their initialization from searchVideos() method.

Answer (score 0):

the exception is caught  i.e as mentioned is in onClick() line 71 shows that it is SAXException so check the code related to SAXException in your method SearchVideos() as this is the method which throwing this exception caught by the catch at line 71.